# Add and receive custom data in db by custom admin menu

Tags: wordpress, sql-update, sql-insert

For my Wordpress application I want to create a section with user reviews. The reviews will not be added by the user but comes by e-mail and should be added by the administrator.

I created a plugin already to set a new admin top level menu named 'User reviews'.
In this plugin I will create a widget too to show the inserted data later in the template.

What I try to reach in the admin page is something like this.

- Click on menu item 'User reviews';

  - Admin can add a new user review
  - All written user reviews are displayed
  - Admin can modify a review

I am wondering how things work with Wordpress to create something like this. Do I need to create new table fields by myself? Do I put custom code to my plugin admin to make things work? (I can program with php/mysql). Or do I use Wordpress classes to create this all?

I don't need to know something such as an option page
because this is what I found a lot on the internet and not really what I am searching for(?)

Comment: you can create a costom post type called review and offer a form to add review to customer. and when they will add a review, insert it as a new post of type = `review` but `post_status` = `draft` now you can check all drafts edit them and finally publish them

Comment: I took the liberty of removing the "recommendation" part of your Q, it's off-topic in all [se]. Your question is of WP architecture & I think it's off-topic here. Oh, you're looking for Custom Post Types.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [wordpress.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom post type, and when a visitor creates a new "review" with your custom form create the post with a status of draft. Email a link to the administrator for them to edit the review. When the administrator approves / rejects it, they can publish / delete it.

Comment: Ideally, you would write a plugin that creates this custom post type. Lots of info on how to create them at http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Comment: It's not going that deep. No users will be able to add reviews. There is one user and that's the Admin. Only the admin can create reviews.